# Asserting the behavior of an handler of an EventEmitter event

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to jest, sorry if this is a trivial question but I went through the official jest docs and I am not able to find a solution to the problem.

I am developing a very simple app in nodejs that consumes data from a websocket and propagates it downstream to a set of consumers via zeromq.

The code is the following:

**app.js**:

```
const initializer = require("./dependencyInitializer");

const sock = initializer.zmqSock();
const ws = initializer.wsClient();

ws.on('update', data => {
  sock.send([data.topic, JSON.stringify(data)]);
});
```

The websocket client is a class from a third party library extending from EventEmitter.

I would like to create a test asserting that the `sock.send` function is called exactly once inside the handler of the 'update' event.

This is my approach:

**app.spec.js**:

```
const ws = require("./app");
const initializer = require("./dependencyInitializer");

jest.mock("./dependencyInitializer", () => {
    return {
        wsClient: jest.fn(() => {
            const EventEmitter = require("events")
            const emitter = new EventEmitter()

            return emitter;
        }),
        zmqSock: jest.fn(() => {
            return {
                send: jest.fn()
            }
        })
    }
});
describe('on message received from websocket',() => {
    it('should pass it to zmq', () => {
        const data = {result: "ok"};

        expect(initializer.wsClient).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(initializer.zmqSock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        const _sock = initializer.zmqSock();
        const _ws = initializer.wsClient();
        _ws.emit("update", data);
        expect(_sock.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

The test fails with the following:

```
on message received from websocket › should pass it to zmq

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      28 |         const _ws = initializer.wsClient();
      29 |         _ws.emit("update", data);
    > 30 |         expect(_sock.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                            ^
      31 |     });
      32 | });
```

I am not sure if I am on the right path, I would like to understand what would be the best approach to develop a test like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mocking by `jest.mock()`, when the `.wsClient()` and `.zmqSock()` methods are called in the `app.js` file and `app.spec.js` file, the `sock` and `ws` objects in `app.js` are different with the `app.spec.js`.

```js
{
  wsClient: jest.fn(() => {
    const EventEmitter = require("events")
    const emitter = new EventEmitter()
    return emitter;
  })
}
```

Every time you call `.wsClient()`, it will create a new object.

Emitter can only listen for events from its own `emit`.  The solution is to create the mock `emitter` and `sock` objects in the mock factory.

`app.js`:

```js
const initializer = require('./dependencyInitializer');

const sock = initializer.zmqSock();
const ws = initializer.wsClient();

ws.on('update', (data) => {
  sock.send([data.topic, JSON.stringify(data)]);
});

module.exports = { sock, ws };
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require('./app');
const initializer = require('./dependencyInitializer');

jest.mock(
  './dependencyInitializer',
  () => {
    const EventEmitter = require('events');
    const emitter = new EventEmitter();
    const mSock = { send: jest.fn() };
    return {
      wsClient: jest.fn(() => emitter),
      zmqSock: jest.fn(() => mSock),
    };
  },
  { virtual: true }
);
describe('on message received from websocket', () => {
  it('should pass it to zmq', () => {
    const data = { result: 'ok' };

    expect(initializer.wsClient).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(initializer.zmqSock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    const _sock = initializer.zmqSock();
    const _ws = initializer.wsClient();

    // check if they have same reference
    expect(app.sock).toBe(_sock);
    expect(app.ws).toBe(_ws);

    _ws.emit('update', data);
    expect(_sock.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/70024105/app.test.js (9.279 s)
  on message received from websocket
    ✓ should pass it to zmq (2 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 app.js   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.112 s
```